# translating preg_replace to jquery replace

Tags: jquery, regex, replace, preg-replace

Hi i am having difficulty translating the preg replace in php to jquery replace....the code i am using given below...regex not being strong point...

```
 dcis_ccnum="3433-4343-3434-3434";
    dcis_ccnum.replace(/(?!^.?)[0-9](?!(.){0,3}$)/, '*');
    alert(dcis_ccnum);
```

what the alert gives me is 3433-4343-3434-3434 what it should do give me is  3***-***-***-3434.

the php code works well

```
echo $dcis_ccnum1=preg_replace('/(?!^.?)[0-9](?!(.){0,3}$)/', '*', '3433-4343-3434-3434');
```

can someone let me know what i am doing wrong ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `g` (global) modifier.

```
dcis_ccnum="3433-4343-3434-3434";
dcis_ccnum = dcis_ccnum.replace(/(?!^.?)[0-9](?!(.){0,3}$)/g, '*');
document.write(dcis_ccnum);
```

Output:

```
3***-****-****-3434
```

By default `string.replace` in JavaScript will only replace the first matching value it finds. Adding the `/g` will mean that all of the matching values are replaced.